Not able to get traces into kafka consumer from Open Telemetry collector
Not able to get traces into Kafka consumer output from collector. please find the below otel-config file.
Our pipeline is from our app--otel-kafka, spans are getting generated and displayed in the otel output debug log. But not going to Kafka topic and no error msg either. If I post a msg directly to Kafka from any other producer, data is received to Kafka. Request to let me know what would be the issue or any way i can debug more?
Starting the collector with below command:
 docker run -d \ -p 4317:4317 -v $(pwd)/otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol/otel-collector-config.yaml \ otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
otel-collector-config.yaml
receivers:
otlp:
protocols:
grpc:

processors:
batch:
queued_retry:

exporters:
debug:
verbosity: detailed
kafka:
brokers:
- localhost:9092
protocol_version: 3.7.1

service:
pipelines:
traces:
receivers: [otlp]
processors: [batch]
exporters: [debug,kafka,logging]
telemetry:
logs:
level: "debug"
encoding: "json"
development: true

Thanks
Tried enabling full debug mode at kafka to check if any errors, still no messages. Otel config also not throwing any errors.
